# Create a search activity like in instagram and twitter

Tags: java, android, xml

In my project I want the search activity to display two types of data in the search activity (restaurants and meals) and I want to implement it like in Twitter and Instagram, my approach is as follows:

in the search activity I created two fragments with each one having a simple list view, my data gets displayed when launching the app but list views don't display all the items at ones, instead, it makes them scroll (in Instagram search activity it shows the suggested and recent items with full height)

**this is the code**

search activity:

```
package com.byshy.light.Activities;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import com.byshy.light.Fragments.SearchRestaurantsFragment;
import com.byshy.light.R;
import com.byshy.light.SearchMealsFragment;

public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.search_restaurants_frag, new SearchRestaurantsFragment()).commit();

        FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction2.replace(R.id.search_meals_frag, new SearchMealsFragment()).commit();

    }

}
```

search activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.SearchActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/search_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:transitionName="search_bar">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/main_screen_search_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/curved_layout"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</FrameLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/search_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_restaurants_frag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_meals_frag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

restaurants fragment:

```
package com.byshy.light.Fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.byshy.light.R;

public class SearchRestaurantsFragment extends Fragment {

ListView lv1;

public SearchRestaurantsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_restaurants, container, false);

    lv1 = root.findViewById(R.id.search_restaurants_list_view);

    String[] items1 = new String[3];

    items1[0] = "res1";
    items1[1] = "res2";
    items1[2] = "res3";

    ArrayAdapter<String> aa1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items1);

    lv1.setAdapter(aa1);

    return root;
}

}
```

meals fragment:

```
package com.byshy.light;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SearchMealsFragment extends Fragment {

ListView lv2;

public SearchMealsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_meals, container, false);

    lv2 = root.findViewById(R.id.search_meals_list_view);

    String[] items2 = new String[10];

    items2[0] = "meal1";
    items2[1] = "meal2";
    items2[2] = "meal3";
    items2[3] = "meal4";
    items2[4] = "meal5";
    items2[5] = "meal6";
    items2[6] = "meal7";
    items2[7] = "meal8";
    items2[8] = "meal9";
    items2[9] = "meal10";

    ArrayAdapter<String> aa2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items2);

    lv2.setAdapter(aa2);

    return root;
}

}
```

the fragments xml is basically the same with some id differences so I will post just one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SearchMealsFragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/small_search_restaurants_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="@string/meals"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:text="@string/more"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/search_meals_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after not finding anything useful on the internet I came up with a new approach to solve this problem.

my new approach is more efficient and it works by creating a model for search results which contains a string and an integer to indicate if the view is a header or a result, then created a item view that contains a linear layout that gets hidden if the view is a not a header, this logic is done inside the adapter.

**this is the code:**

this is the search_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/search_item_back_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="2dp">

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:background="#f9f9f9"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/search_result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

new searchActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Activities.SearchActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:transitionName="search_bar">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/main_screen_search_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/curved_layout"
            android:hint="@string/search"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="10dp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/search_activity_results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

searchActivity.java

```
package com.byshy.light.Activities;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import com.byshy.light.Adapters.SearchResultsAdapter;
import com.byshy.light.Models.SearchResult;
import com.byshy.light.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView searchRV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

    searchRV = findViewById(R.id.search_activity_results);
    searchRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
    searchRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    ArrayList<SearchResult> results = new ArrayList<>();
    results.add(new SearchResult("Restaurants", 1));
    results.add(new SearchResult("res1"));
    results.add(new SearchResult("res2"));
    results.add(new SearchResult("res3"));
    results.add(new SearchResult("Meals", 1));
    results.add(new SearchResult("meal1"));
    results.add(new SearchResult("meal2"));
    results.add(new SearchResult("meal3"));
    results.add(new SearchResult("meal4"));
    results.add(new SearchResult("meal5"));
    results.add(new SearchResult("meal6"));

    SearchResultsAdapter adapter = new SearchResultsAdapter(results);

    searchRV.setAdapter(adapter);

}

}
```

SearchResultsAdapter.java

```
package com.byshy.light.Adapters;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.byshy.light.Models.SearchResult;
import com.byshy.light.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SearchResultsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchResultsAdapter.SearchResultViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<SearchResult> mData;

public SearchResultsAdapter(ArrayList<SearchResult> data) {
    mData = data;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public SearchResultViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.search_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new SearchResultViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchResultViewHolder searchResultViewHolder, int i) {
    SearchResult searchResult = mData.get(i);
    searchResultViewHolder.result.setText(searchResult.getContent());
    if (searchResult.getType() == 0) {
        searchResultViewHolder.backBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        searchResultViewHolder.setClickable(true);
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) searchResultViewHolder.result.getLayoutParams();
        params.leftMargin = 8;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

class SearchResultViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView result;
    private LinearLayout backBar;
    private View view;

    public SearchResultViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;
        result = itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_result);
        backBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_item_back_bar);
    }

    public void setClickable(boolean clickable) {
        view.setClickable(clickable);
        view.setFocusable(clickable);
    }

}

}
```

[the end product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXDnc.png)